# How can I use a deferred object to retrieve a longitude and latitude with the HTML5 Geolocation API?

Tags: jquery, geolocation, promise, deferred

I'd like to use the HTML5 GeoLocation API to retrieve my longitude and latitude and manage the request using a jQuery Deferred object.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var geoLocation = {

    getLocation: function() {

        // create deferred object
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        // if geo location is supported
        if(navigator.geolocation) {

            // get current position and pass the results to this.geoLocationSuccess or time out after 5 seconds if it fails
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoLocationSuccess, this.geoLocationError, {
                timeout: 5000
            });

        } else {

            // geo location isn't supported
            console.log('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
        }

    },

    geoLocationSuccess: function(position) {

        // resolve deffered object
        deferred.resolve(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        // return promise
        return deferred.promise();
    },

    geoLocationError: function() {
        console.log('Geo Location failed.');
    }

};
```

And here is my Deferred object:

```
$.when(geoLocation.getLocation()).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    console.log(data);

});
```

I'm expecting the longitude and latitude to be returned by the `then()` callback but instead, I get the error that `deferred` is undefined. I think it has something to do with the scope of where I define my deferred object but I'm not sure. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

Michael, after reading Hackaholic's answer and your own, both will work with regard to handling successfully returned data, but errors could be better handled.

If `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` fails, it will pass a potentially informative [PositionError](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation.getCurrentPosition) object to its error handler. This object, which can be passed down the promise chain and handled in the calling function, is disregarded in both answers.

Similarly, promise rejection can also be used to pass your own "Your browser does not support Geo Location" error down the promise chain.

```
var geoLocation = {
    getLocation: function() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            // geo location is supported. Call navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition and :
            // - resolve the promise with the returned Position object, or
            // - reject the promise with the returned PositionError object, or
            // - time out after 5 seconds
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject, { timeout: 5000 });
        } else {
            //geo location isn't supported
            //Reject the promise with a suitable error message
            deferred.reject(new Error('Your browser does not support Geo Location.'));
        }
        return deferred.promise();
    } 
};
```

Ignoring the comments, this is very compact and note how `geoLocation.getLocation()` makes no attempt to handle errors but makes them available to the calling function's error handler.

Now, `$.when()` is not necessary because your `geoLocation.getLocation()` function returns a promise which has its own `.then()` method. It is already "thenable" without `$.when()`.

```
geoLocation.getLocation().then(function(position) {
    console.dir(position);
}).fail(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Thus, you fully exploit the ability of the promise to handle success or failure.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this answer, because you're absolutely right that errors should be handled better. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out, but I should actually credit Scott Allen at [Ode to Code](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/18/geolocation-geocoding-and-jquery-promises.aspx).

**The function(s) that `$.when()` is waiting to resolve must return the `promise()` directly.**

In my case I was resolving the deferred object and returning the `promise()` in the `getCurrentLocation()` callback function, not the function I had specified in `$.when()`.

### SOLUTION:

```
var geoLocation = {

    getLocation: function() {

        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        // if geo location is supported
        if(navigator.geolocation) {

            // get current position and pass the results to getPostalCode or time out after 5 seconds if it fails
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, this.geoLocationError, {
                timeout: 5000
            });

        } else {

            //geo location isn't supported
            console.log('Your browser does not support Geo Location.');
        }

        return deferred.promise();

    },

    geoLocationError: function() {
        console.log('Geo Location failed.');
    }

};

$.when(geoLocation.getLocation()).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    console.log(data.coords.longitude, data.coords.latitude);

});
```